# Role Based Shared Control Panel

Tags: 7

I'm looking for a way to allow members of a specific role to share a control panel/settings page.  These users do not have admin level access and I would like to use the field api to store data.

Currently I'm leaning towards the Profile2 module, but this doesn't feel very robust.

Is there a common way to accomplish this that I've missed, a module that is better suited for this use case or am I on the right track using the Profile2 module?

Comment: check this https://drupal.org/project/fcontrolpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with the combination of `profile2` and `og` (organic group)  you can achieve your job.